# Ruby on Rails active admin as dashboard for every user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am relatively new to Ruby on Rails and activeadmin. I wonder how I can make active_admin as a user control dashboard. User loged into admin dashboard, only seeing their own records, i.e posts and account info and etc. Also, I already have CanCAn role based user authorization

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/How-to-work-with-cancan

Based on the article pasted above, it is possible to create user only access their own records.